# Оптимизация пересечения лучей с mesh моделью

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, raytracing

Есть ли оптимизированный метод, позволяющий получить все треугольники mesh видимые с заданной точки?

есть mesh модель огромного размера и некая точка вблизи этой модели. С точки разлетаются лучи условно на все 360 градусов. Надо вычислить индексы всех треугольников, на которые попадают лучи из этой точки. Аналогия видеокамеры...

Понятно, что методы пересечения лучей с сеткой, реализованные в таких библиотеках как trimesh или pymesh неэффективны на больших моделях.
Большая модель в моём случае, это миллиарды вершин...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На картинке изображена относительно маленькая модель здания, на углу внутреннего двора размещен источник лучей с ограниченной дальностью. Я пытаюсь вычислить те треугольники, на которые луч попадет первым. То есть, если источник лучей считать за источник света, то он будет освещать внутренний двор, а не всю модель.
Результат на картинке получен с помощью trimesh.ray.intersects_first.

Comment: По какой причине треугольник может быть не видим из точки?

Comment: Когда луч проходит сквозь модель, он может пересекать несколько треугольников. Мне нужно только первое пересечение. Остальные пересеченные треугольники - будут невидимыми.

Comment: То есть только самозатенение? Ограничения по near/far plane есть? 360 градусов - означает что рендерится целиком вся сфера? Лучи по сфере в регулярном порядке пускаются? Или надо делать пересечение для произвольного луча в произвольном направлении?

Comment: Как устроен меш? Это один большой ландшафт? Или куча объектов как предметы в комнате? Насколько велики треугольники по сравнению со всей сценой? Сильно ли меняются размеры треугольников? Почему не используются ЛОДы? Если можно, добавьте в вопрос картинку со сценой.

Comment: Я добавил картинку с неудачной визуализацией обработки маленькой модели.

Comment: Меш - карта высот? Или там могут быть веши сложнее?

Comment: это примерно как 3D модель территории города

Comment: Пробовали https://github.com/mhogg/pyoctree ? octree хорошо соответствует задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел оптимизированное решение с помощью embree в trimesh.

```
import trimesh
import numpy as np


mesh = trimesh.creation.icosphere(use_embree=True)

cam = np.array([[0, 0, -3]])
ray_origins = np.tile(cam, (len(mesh.vertices), 1))
ray_directions = mesh.vertices-np.tile(cam, (len(mesh.vertices), 1))

index_tri, index_ray = mesh.ray.intersects_id(
        ray_origins=ray_origins,
        ray_directions=ray_directions, multiple_hits=False)

ray_visualize = trimesh.load_path(np.hstack((ray_origins,
                                             ray_origins + ray_directions*1.0)).reshape(-1, 2, 3))

mesh.visual.face_colors = [255,255,255,255]
mesh.visual.face_colors[index_tri] = [255, 0, 0, 255]

scene = trimesh.Scene([mesh, ray_visualize])
scene.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако оно выдает результаты с некоторыми ошибками. На эту тему открыл другой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1570065/%D0%92-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-trimesh-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0).